# How to extract href detail from links using Jsoup?

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

I have an html with this form:

```
 <table> 
               <tbody>
                <tr> 
                 <td class="t1"><a href="/click/site1" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><img class="png" src="" alt="site1"></a></td> 
                 <td class="t2 up"><a href="/click/site1" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">INFORMATION</a></td> 
                 <td class="t2 down"><a href="/click/site1" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">INFORMATION</a></td> 
                 <td class="t2 up mark"><a href="/click/site1" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">INFORMATION</a></td> 
                </tr>
                <tr> 
                 <td class="t1"><a href="/click/site2" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><img class="png" src="" alt="site2"></a></td> 
                 <td class="t2 down"><a href="/click/site2" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">INFORMATION</a></td> 
                 <td class="t2 stable"><a href="/click/site2" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">INFORMATION</a></td> 
                 <td class="t2 up"><a href="/click/site2" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">INFORMATION</a></td> 
                </tr>
                 .
                 . 
                 .
              </tbody> 
 </table>
```

and I want to extract or the value of href (/click/site1) or the value of alt (site1).
How  can I do this using Jsoup??
thx

edit:
this is the code that I wrote:

```
for(Element table : doc.select("table"))
        {

            for(Element row : table.select("tr"))
            {
                System.out.print(table.attr("href").toString());
                Elements column = row.select("td");
                {
                System.out.println(column.text());
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```

but this line `System.out.print(table.attr("href").toString());`doesn't print anything

Answer (score 2):

This process is described in jsoup cookbook.

http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/working-with-urls

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://jsoup.org").get();

Element link = doc.select("a").first();
String relHref = link.attr("href"); // == "/"
String absHref = link.attr("abs:href"); // "http://jsoup.org/"
```

In your question you try to get the attribute href from the table but the table doesn't have href attribute. Either you search for all a tags or you may select the td inside your row and then the link inside of that.

Did some coding add changed your example and added some code to only write the links.

```
for(Element table : doc.select("table")) {
    for(Element row : table.select("tr")) {
        Elements column = row.select("td");
        Elements atag = column.get(0).select("a");
        System.out.print(atag.get(0).attr("href").toString());
        System.out.print(" ");
        System.out.println(column.text());
    }
    System.out.println();
}

for(Element link : doc.select("a")) {
    System.out.println(link.attr("href")); // == "/"
}
```